# What do I need to consider when collaborating on an R project with GitHub and a shared OneDrive folder?

Tags: r, git, github, onedrive

I hope that this is the right place for this question and that the title speaks for itself.

**Background**
I need to collaborate on an R project and be able to work on and run scripts at the same time as my collaborators.

All collaborators can access shared folders on OneDrive. This seems to somehow make GitHub obsolete for the code-sharing part and OneDrive also seems to have the ability to revert to previous file versions.

---

**Potential problem**
However, I can imagine that working on the same R-script on the shared OneDrive folder will result in conflicts and that this is better controlled via GitHub.

---

**Question**
My question in other words: what should I consider when collaborating on such a project?

For example: should I not use a shared OneDrive folder and have the R project run locally and solely use GitHub for code sharing and collaboration?

Thank you for your input and suggestions.

Comment: I see the commonality, but "previous file versions" is not a perfect replacement for "intentional (commented) file commits"; just because OneDrive has a new file does not mean that that file is ready for other users to use. Conflicts can occur in either situation, though merge-conflicts on github is perhaps a little better define (though still not always trivial to resolve). What is the frequency of change? Are different users responsible for different areas of the code?

Comment: Thank you. In fact all user need to be able to make changes in the same files at any time. These times can coincide and I guess that, as you mention, conflicts could be worse to solve with OneDrive.

Comment: If you _must_ do that (good luck!), look outside of RStudio and R into "collaborative file editing". It's a hard thing to do well, none of them are based on OneDrive or github, and from the little I know, most (all?) of them are based on "collaborative ***document*** editing", typically referring to rich documents (e.g., Word, Powerpoint, or online variants). Google drive supports it, I believe, as does Word Online, but I don't know if/how to do that with simple-text `.R` files.

Comment: Thanks again. This is exactly my question/problem.

Comment: StackOverflow is not intended to be a software-recommendation site, though some questions push the envelope a bit. I think this question is smack in the center of *"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"* from [help/on-topic]. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is intended for this, though it doesn't have the visit-rate of SO.

Comment: I disagree with this assessment and intend the question to generally cover "software tools commonly used by programmers [...]" in combination with a "practical, answerable problem that is a unique software development" (i.e., version control AND code sharing/collaboration for R) as per help center.